# Delete files older than the epoch date of a file in a list

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting, find

I have a file which contains a full path of a filename (space separated) and the last column I put the change date of the file in epoch.

```
/data/owncloud/c/files/Walkthrough 2019/#25 SEC-C03/Group Enterprise.jpg 1569314988
```

I want to delete all space separated files which epoch number is smaller then 1568187717.

The script looks like this at the moment, but this if with the space separation can't work :(

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
while read i
        do printf "%s " "$i"
        stat --format=%Z $i
done < <(find /data/owncloud/*/files -type f) > filelistwithchangeddate

filetodelete=expr `date +'%s'` - 2592000
```

The `awk '{print $(NF)}'` has the last column number so somehow need to compare the awk output with the filetodelete and delete the space separated files.

**Update:**
Something like this what it should be I think:

```
for i in `cat filelistwithchangeddate `
do
if [ $(awk '{print $(NF)}' $i) -lt $filetodelete ]
then
echo "this will be deleted:"
awk '{$NF=""}1' $i
fi
done
```

But need to fix somehow the spaces and run the delete

Comment: Can you use `find . ! -neweryourFile` ? It will also return files with the same age, so I did not post it as an answer and did not add `-rm`.

Comment: Your update seems to attempt to reimplement `awk -v epoch="$filetodelete" '$NF<epoch' filewithchangeddate` with a five-dimensional pretzel.

Comment: @WalterA you can post I don’t know how you mean.

Comment: @tripleee so how to fix?

Comment: The script I posted *is* the fix. If it doesn't do what you expect, maybe clarify what you actually expect.

Comment: I see, ok, and how about the delete? Any idea? Delete the files of your output, so the space separated files before the last column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Thank you triplee, I think this will work:

```
IFS=$'\n'
while read i
        do printf "%s " "$i"
        stat --format=%Z $i
done < <(find /data/owncloud/*/files -type f) > /root/script/newpurge/filelistwithchangeddate


filetodelete=$(expr `date +'%s'` - 2592000)


awk -v epoch="$filetodelete" '$NF<epoch' /root/script/newpurge/filelistwithchangeddate > oldf
iles

awk '{$NF=""}1' /root/script/newpurge/oldfiles > marktodelete
sed -i "s/^/'/g" /root/script/newpurge/marktodelete
sed -i "s/[ ]\+$/'/g" /root/script/newpurge/marktodelete

for i in $(cat /root/script/newpurge/marktodelete)
do
        rm -f $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58132736/8344060):

This can easily done using `find`. Normally you would do:

```
$ find . -type f ! -newermt "@1569314988" -delete
```

but if you want to pick the time from a file (example from OP):

```
$ t=$(awk '{print NF}' file)
$ [[ "$t" != "" ]] && find . -type f ! -newermt "@${t}" -delete
```

See `man find` for details on the meaning of the flags and for extra modifications which might be needed.

Comment: Maxdepth 1 is not good, I don’t know how deep need to go in the directory

Comment: @Badb0y updated. But realize that this is a "generic" answer and is not necessarily 100% tuned to solve the OP. It, however, can be used to solve the OP.